# What is the assembly equivalent of C++ function overloading?

Tags: c++, function, assembly, overloading

I have been lately trying to translate C++ fundamentals into assembly code, and one thing does not make sense to me yet. How is function overloading actually translated into assembly code from C++ code? Assembly only supports procedures with unique. So what is the mechanism behind the function overloading in C++. Is it some kind of function pointers at work, or is it calling a macro? I could not find any relevant articles on the net about this.

Is there any specified technique followed by all compilers, or does the technique vary?

Comment: Yes this technique is called "name mangling".

Comment: Not putting this as an answer because I don't know for certain, but I'm pretty sure the compiler gives each function overload a unique name so that in the assembly you actually don't have any overloaded functions.

Comment: You can [try it out](https://godbolt.org/z/decEoj)

Comment: Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C++), it should answer your question.

Comment: @NathanOliver If it is so, then how does the compiler differentiate between function calls. Is it done at runtime or compile time. If it is done at runtime, I see no tangible way the .exe file can find out which function name to call.

Comment: Think of a C++ function as having the parameter types as part of the name. E.g. `foo(int a, double b)` is `foo__int__double`. The compiler decides on which `foo` to call *at compilation time* based on the rules of overload resolution.

Comment: @ForceBru One can disable demangling, which makes it even more obvious that they are just named differently depending on parameters (`_Z3addii` and `_Z3addiii`) https://godbolt.org/z/e16rad

Comment: @debanshudas All function calls happen at compile time (baring virtual functions be even all of that information is known at compile time).  Since it knows the which overload to use. it replaces the call to the overloaded function to a call the particular overload that now has a unique name.

Comment: In my experience with assembly languages, assembly languages don't have functions.  They have labels (which are optional).  They have one-way branch statements.  Some assembly languages have instructions that branch and store the return addresses.  Some assembly languages have "return" instructions.  I haven't seen any assembly language that supports functions like higher level languages have.  Compilers can pass parameters through registers or other means.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews They have functions. They are written as labels that are jumped to with a `call` instruction and they have specific preambles and endings. Also they are labelled to the linker as functions in some cases.

Comment: Actually, the different "variants" of one method are different functions. If you convert C++ to C code, `myFunc(int a)` becomes `myFunc_int(int a)` and `myFunc(char b, char c)` becomes `myFunc_char_char(char b, char c)`. Early C++ compilers generated C code from C++ code and a C compiler was used to generate the assembly code. So in the assembly code you find two different functions that correspond to the two variants of the overloaded method. This is still the case for modern C++ compilers.

Answer (score 3):

As @n.'pronouns'm. and several others said in the comments, each separate function overload is given a special name in assembly by the compiler. This names encodes both the function name and the parameter types. Thus different function overloads are distinguished in assembly, both when declared and when called.

Answer (score 2):

**TL:DR: overloading is basically a source-level thing that makes the arg types part of the function "name".**  There's no *real* equivalent in hand-written asm.  Asm doesn't even have a type system; it's up to you to use sensible instructions that do something useful with the bit-patterns in registers.

C++ compilers *implement* it in asm by using "name mangling" so the asm symbol name for `foo(int, int)` is for example `_Z3fooii`.  ([Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/WTqWKs)).

---

**Function overloading in C++ is statically resolved at compile time.  No function pointers or any other runtime shenanigans are involved.**

It effectively makes the types of the args part of the function name.  So for hand-written asm, the equivalent could be some simple manual scheme like `foo_int`, `foo_float`, `foo_int_int`, etc.  Each with a separate definition, exactly like 3 separate functions with totally different names.

C++ enables much more code-reuse (especially via templates) than asm.  You could imagine trying to do something in asm with macros, where maybe you have a macro arg that's a string like `int` or something.  But unless the macro *only* stitches together calls to other functions (by tacking on the string to some base-name, like `call foo_%1` / `mov rdi, rax` / `call bar_%1`), this doesn't really work in asm (because each instruction doing real work has to use registers of the right size).

I guess maybe for a macro that takes register names as macro parameters, it could expand to `add rax, rsi` or `add eax, esi` depending on what the caller passed, and it could pass `long` or `int` to match.  (So the macro is like a template function with the type as a template param; the overloading is just in the calls that use the type name as part of the asm symbol name.)    That can of course only work in limited circumstances.  e.g. `float` needs different mnemonics than `int` or `long` as well as different register names, on most ISAs.